# iPhone: Is it possible to put a link in Push-Notifications?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to put a link in Push-Notifications message? I wish to send video link as notification.

Answer (score 5):

No and Yes, you can't directly put a link the notifiocation it self, but you can but some userInfo in the notification.

Then in your app check if there is extra information in de userInfo, such as a link, and handle it acordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Actually I need to send the users with newly added video links(as we can do with mobile sms)

Comment: Hi @Vindo A, would you tell me what you did, did you manage to add a link to the notification? if not, did you find any workaround?

Comment: The workaround is as follows:

Include a key/value pair in the push.  When the user opens the app from the push (default push behavior), the app responds to the key/value pair and sends the user wherever, including opening a browser window.